# Postgresql DB to MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, export

I want to export my postgresql database in a .sql file that mysql can read to import. Currently MySQL throw this error: `Unknown system variable 'statement_timeout'`.

How can i do that?

**EDIT:**

1. With pgAdmin 4, right click on backup...
2. Name file: test.sqsl
3. Format: plain
4. And Save

Comment: Could you share code/procedure you adopted?

Comment: In general, I would expect a Postgres proc to be non compatible with MySQL.  Please show us your code.

Comment: I'm betting you have to go through a migration process for all dml and ddl code.You could start by reading this https://mysqlworkbench.org/2012/11/how-to-migrate-postgresql-databases-to-mysql-using-the-mysql-workbench-migration-wizard/